# What does the word "no" mean before a noun-adjective word?

Tags: meaning, negation

I see some examples :

**- No cheese**

**- No errors**

**- No good**

I understand how to use "**any**", but "**no**" before a noun is weird (especially **"no"** before an adjective). Can anyone explain them?

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but are you familiar with the concept of homonyms?

Comment: I think this is General Reference - too basic for ELU, but would probably be fine on [Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, **no** is essentially the same as **not any.**  So, there is not any cheese, there are zero errors, and something is not good.

This is meaning #2 in [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/no).

That said, there's room for interpretation here. Just like *NO DIVING* can mean "diving is not allowed," *NO CHEESE* could mean "do not put any cheese in this dish" (which might be something said to a cook, when the diners might be lactose intolerant).

Answer (score 1):

the context isn't totally clear here, but generally in front of a noun (like cheese, errors and sometimes good) 'no' indicates that there is "not any".

ex. No cheese is made from cat's milk. =  There is not any type of cheese made from cat's milk.

ex. No errors were found in the document.  = There are not any errors (that were found) in the document.

"Good" is slightly different.  Good can be a noun in the same way as above.
ex. No good can come from playing with guns.

The expression "no good" can also be used as a noun in the following way:
ex. She was up to no good.  (ie she was misbehaving/ doing something mischievous)

but people do also use no-good as an adjective--  ex. He is no good which basically just means he's bad.

I think this is just a oddity of the word "good" though as I can't think of any other adjectives that are used in this way.

Answer (score 1):

"No" simply indicates *an absence* of whatever it's qualifying.

No cheese: there is an absence of cheese;
No errors: there is an absence of errors;
No good: there is an absence of good.

Note that *good* here is not an adjective per se; it's a [noun](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/good?q=good).

Comment: I'd class _no good_ as a compound - adjective (This screwdriver is no good = useless; a no-good punk) - **or** noun (up to no good = mischief) (as Sarah Liz says). _No use_ is an alternative (for useless). The latter is probably a reduced PP (_**of** no use_).

Comment: @edwin See the ODO link. No good = No benefit [noun-2].